# CSS flex columns with ordering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the following:

`cw` stands for calendar week.
I want to get exactly the following order of items - with it being dynamically changed every week since there will be a new calendar week and thus a new item:

```
a (CW 3)    f (CW 50)
b (CW 2)    g (CW 49)
c (CW 1)    h (CW 48)
d (CW 52)   i (CW 47) 
e (CW 51)   j (CW 46)
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-container {
  flex-basis: 75%;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-con {
  flex-basis: 25%;
}

#footer {
    max-width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
  }
   
   #footer .item {
    flex-basis: 45%;
    max-width: 105%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="item">a (CW 3)</div>
            <div class="item">b (CW 2)</div>
            <div class="item">c (CW 1)</div>
            <div class="item">d (CW 52)</div>
            <div class="item">e (CW 51)</div>
            <div class="item">f (CW 50)</div>
            <div class="item">g (CW 49)</div>
            <div class="item">h (CW 48)</div>
            <div class="item">i (CW 47)</div>
            <div class="item">j (CW 46)</div>
            <div class="item">k (CW 45)</div>
            <div class="item">l (CW 44)</div>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="flex-con">
         <div>bla</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I want to order the items by their calendar week. They are only allowed to take 2 columns of the `flex-container` (75% flex-basis).

Comment: I don't think you want `flex` for that, you want `column-count:2`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<div id="footer">
<div class="grid-container">
        <div class="item">a (CW 3)</div>
        <div class="item">b (CW 2)</div>
        <div class="item">c (CW 1)</div>
        <div class="item">d (CW 52)</div>
        <div class="item">e (CW 51)</div>
        <div class="item">f (CW 50)</div>
        <div class="item">g (CW 49)</div>
        <div class="item">h (CW 48)</div>
        <div class="item">i (CW 47)</div>
        <div class="item">j (CW 46)</div>
 </div>
 <div class="flex-con">
     <div>bla</div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}


#footer {
    max-width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
  }
   
   #footer .item {
    flex-basis: 45%;
    max-width: 105%;
  }
```

Something like that should work